# Clean up issue when a class has properties of stream type

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a class that has properties of stream type, as below:

```
public class Csv
{
  private StreamReader streadReder;
  private StreamWriter streamWriter;
}
```

Does it require implementation of `IDisposable`? If needed, please provide links. As it seems a bit confusing to impalement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should implement IDisposable in such cases. There is even a design warning in Code analysis for this: *[CA1001: Types that own disposable fields should be disposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182172.aspx).*

The simplest implementation could look like this:

```
public class Csv : IDisposable
{
    private StreamReader streadReader;
    private StreamWriter streamWriter;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (streadReader != null)
        {
            streadReader.Dispose();
        }

        if (streamWriter != null)
        {
            streamWriter.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you run the analysis? I am using VS 2012? I ran Run Code Analysis, but it has no warning. Is there other similar tools, like FoxCop, Style something, which you will recommend?

Comment: You can select different rule sets on Code Analysis tab of project's properties. For instance, using "Microsoft Basic Design Guideline Rules" will make this warning appear.

Comment: In our project we are using StyleCop with ReSharper, which helps maintain some reasonable level of code quality and style consistency.

Comment: Do I miss something. I cannot get that warning even if I use "Microsoft All rules".

Answer (score 1):

If the `Csv` type owns the stream resources and is responsible for their disposal then it should implement `IDipsosable` as well and Dispose of the values

```
public class Csv : IDisposable { 
  ...
  public void Dispose() { 
    streamReader.Dispose();
    streamWriter.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds what I am thinking. Thanks!